# Owl Carousel item content position

Tags: css, joomla3.0, owl-carousel

Please advise how to move .g-owlcarousel-item-content block to the upper left corner of the Owl Carousel image

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Where's your code? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)